# Document templates not displaying inside a document set

Tags: 2013, content-type, document-set, document-template

I have a document library which at the top has a series of templates when I open it up.  (Site Contents > My Document library > New file
[image: My Document library]

First thing I did, was create a document set.  The example is someone's name, so I named mine "Billy Bob".

When I go to create a document based on one of the templates, they aren't there.
[image: Billy Bob]

Any thoughts, or are templates only available at the top of a document library?

Answer (score 0):

By default OOTB **Document Set** Content type allows only OOTB **Document** content type files to be created inside it.

Go to **Library settings** page--> Click on the Document set content type--> **Document Set Settings** --> Check the **Content types allowed in the Document Set** . Add the content types whose templates you need to be available.
[image]

Now if you are using the OOTB **Document Set** content type, it is highly recommended that you don't make the above change on it directly , but create a new custom document set content type and make the change on it.Use this custom document set content type in library.

Comment: Thanks Unnie.  I thought I had done it before, but that was the answer that I couldn't find.  
Stack Exchange rules!